# Type error not being caught in async await

Tags: javascript, async-await

I have a sql db query promise in the async function `this.db.executeSql`. In some cases the `this.db` will be `undefined`. I expect the `typeerror` that happen to be caught by the `catch`. But I end up getting

> core.js:1449 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot
>   read property 'executeSql' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read
>   property 'executeSql' of undefined

```
  async sqlExecute(sql,params = {}){
    try{
      return await this.db.executeSql(sql,params);
    }catch(err){
      return Promise.reject(err);
    }
  }
```

Whats I am doing wrong?

Comment: Check the value of `this`. The error is saying that it can't find the function `executeSql` on `undefined`, meaning `this.db` is undefined.

Comment: I understand the error. The error is not being caught by ``catch``. Why is that happening?

Comment: I am sorry . It is actually being caught. But I didnt catch the returned Promise.reject . I am just gonna delete the question.